# Error on running reindexing

Tags: magento2, reindex, error-log

When i doing `sudo bin/magento indexer:reindex`, there's 2 error showed like in error below.

Error :

```
Design Config Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Customer Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Category Products index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Product Categories index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Product Price index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:02
Product EAV index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Stock index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog rule indexing failed. See details in exception log.
Catalog rule indexing failed. See details in exception log.
Catalog Search index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:01
```

And when i check the exception log, there's an error like in the code below.

Exception :

```
[2017-12-07 04:34:17] main.CRITICAL: Unable to unserialize value. {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): Unable to unserialize value. at /var/www/html/myshop.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Serialize/Serializer/Json.php:39)"} []
[2017-12-07 04:34:17] main.CRITICAL: Catalog rule indexing failed. See details in exception log. {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\LocalizedException(code: 0): Catalog rule indexing failed. See details in exception log. at /var/www/html/myshop.com/public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog-rule/Model/Indexer/IndexBuilder.php:286)"} []
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: In 2.2 Magento switched from php serialize function to json. For some reasons, your instance contains invalid conditions or actions in catalog rules.

I suggest to recreate catalog rules and run the same cli command again.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it may be a permissions issue, where Magento is setting permissions for generated files that are restricted on whatever sever you're operating on.

I think you could solve this by creating magento_umask file in the root directory with the appropriate umask for the server.

SRC: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/install/post-install-umask.html best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to run following command

**php bin/magento indexer:reset catalogrule_rule**
May be you need to reset those indexer which you have issue.